# how to make a vector of different values in R

Tags: r

I have a matrix (data1) looking like:

```
  gene       S869      S907       S909   S016          S090         S160
1 S1          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
2 S2          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
3 S3          0          0          0   0.423405          0          0
4 S4          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
5 S5          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
6 S6          0          0          0   0.000000          0          0
```

I want to make a vector (Say X) for this matrix. I have another dataset (data2) looking like:

```
Cultivar  Dose
S869  10
S907  5
S909  7
S016  19
S090  15
S160  12
```

Then I want to do a linear regression using

```
for (gene in 1:ngenes){
model = lm(Dose~X[gene,])
}
```

and also want to get the p values from above regression. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we want to use the 'Cultivar' to extract the column names, loop over the 'Cultivar', 'Dose' corresponding values with `Map`, extract the column based on the 'Culivar' value for 'data1', create a new column 'Dose' with `transform` and apply the `lm`, extract the p values from the `coef`ficients

```
lst1 <-  Map(function(x, y) {
   tmpdat <- transform(as.data.frame(data1)[x], Dose = y)
   model <- lm(Dose ~ ., data = tmpdat)
   coef(summary(model))[, "Pr(>|t|)"]}, data2$Cultivar, data2$Dose)

lst1
#$S869
#[1] 1.218223e-78

#$S907
#[1] 1.218223e-78

#$S909
#[1] 2.265096e-79

#...
```

#### data

```
data1 <- structure(list(gene = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S5", "S6"), 
    S869 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S907 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L), S909 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S016 = c(0, 0, 
    0.423405, 0, 0, 0), S090 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), S160 = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

data2 <- structure(list(Cultivar = c("S869", "S907", "S909", "S016", "S090", 
"S160"), Dose = c(10L, 5L, 7L, 19L, 15L, 12L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Thank you! I think I am confused with what dataset you used at what step. I got this  Error in `[.data.frame`(as.data.frame(df), x) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @Jessica the firrst datset you showed is named as 'dat1' and the second with two columns is 'df2'

Comment: I cahnged the names to 'data1' and 'data2'

Comment: @Jessican Do you have the column names  in 'data1' based on the 'Cultivar' column in 'data2'

Comment: @Jessica I updated with the data I used.  I couldn't reproduce the error, there are some warning but that is based on the data

Comment: Yes, but all the row names in data2 are not present in data1. Data1 is a subset of row names in data2. I get it. I changed data2 with only row names same as column names of data1. Sorry for the confusion. Now I am getting this message: There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them). whereas lst1 shows NA for all cultivars. I wanted to mention, in data2 for one variety, dose is NA.

Comment: @Jessica For that case,you can create an index `i1 <- !is.na(data2$Dose)` and in the `Map` pass only the non-NA .e. `data2$Cultivar[i1], data2$Dose[i1])`

Comment: Done. I think I just you to upvote and never accepted the answer. Thank you for bringing it up.

Comment: using the same code on large dataset, I am getting In summary.lm(model) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable. For all the doses, all p values are non-significant. Can you suggest what is going wrong. Thank you!

Comment: @Jessica can you check the summary of your data columns, I think it may give more insights because what we are doing is fitting a model and the model can change drastically based on the values

Comment: @Jessica I would suggest to do the `lm` on a single column and crosscheck with the output you are getting from `Map`.  In that way, you can find if the issue is with the dataset

Comment: @Jessica i.e. you can try this on a single column `coef(summary(lm(Dose ~ S869, transform(data1, Dose = 10))))[, "Pr(>|t|)"]#
[1] 1.218223e-78`

Comment: Thank you, I got the same p value for a single column as of Map output.

Comment: @Jessica then , it would be an issue with the data values

Comment: Can it be an issue as I have nearly half of NA values which are not used in the model.

Comment: @Jessica that could be an issue, because if I rememeber, it could drop those rows

Comment: I think I am getting all non-significant values as there is only one value that I am comparing for.  I have another question. How about if I want to check regression between genes and dose using same two datasets? So that I get p values for all genes for dose across all varieties.

Comment: @Jessica can you please post as a new question. thanks

Comment: Thank you, I have posted a new question.